# Identifying red dot in JPEG picture in microcontroller

Tags: image-processing, camera, embedded, jpeg, microcontroller

I am starting a project in which i'll have to identify a red dot/ball in a JPEG picture - problem is it has to be done on a microcontroller.

I'm pretty much at the bare bottom, so i am seeking inputs to what's needed to make such an operation.

So if I have a JPEG picture in the microcontroller memory, what would the steps towards Identifying the red dot along with it's placement in the picture be?

Thanks in advance :) ..

(By the way, I intent to use this camera, if that makes any difference: https://www.sparkfun.com/products/10061)

Comment: After decoding the jpg. You will need to apply an DSP algorithm to find the ball. You should validate this algorithm in matlab before writing any C code. The algorithm would be a vertical and horizontal scan on the flattened red layer to one dimension.

Answer (score 1):

I would imagine that image processing on JPEG encoded data would be rather difficult, you may first need to decode it perhaps.

If you have insufficient memory for that, there are some papers on compressed domain processing of JPEGs, for example:

- http://www.cs.cornell.edu/zeno/papers/cdp/cdp_rtij96.pdf
- http://signal.ece.utexas.edu/~queiroz/papers/processjpeg.pdf

Comment: Yes, i had also imagined that decoding the JPEG would be the first step - I found this library for decoding https://code.google.com/p/picojpeg/ . But the links seems very usefull too - thanks :) .